# Python initialize var to None?

Tags: python, pycharm, nonetype

What's the difference?

```
myVar: myCustomClassType
```

vs.

```
myVar: myCustomClassType = None
```

I ask because Pycharm inspector squawks w/ the latter:

```
Expected type 'myCustomClassType', got 'None' instead
```

I understand that None is an object too and so therefore this inspection is stating that there is a type clash. 
My question is which is better form?

Comment: *None* is indeed an object (like everything in *Python*), but not an *myCustomClassType* instance.

Comment: Why is that surprising? You might as well write `foo: int = "bar"`.

Comment: What is "better" depends on what you want to achieve. I don't know why you would want to annotate a variable with a type and then bind it to an instance of another, incompatible type. But you might have a good reason to do that. Do you have one?

Comment: Goyo: initialization...? I've always liked Initialization but in this case/context  perhaps I'm wrong.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The first is an example of [Variable Annotation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/), where you use type hints to let type checkers know to associate an identifier (in a particular scope) with some type.

The difference between the two is that

```
myVar: myCustomClassType
```

does not assign any value to `myVar`, while the second does.  If you intend for `myVar` to have either a `None` value or a `myCustomClassType` value, you should use the [`Optional`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Optional) generic type from the `typing` module:

```
from typing import Optional 

myVar: Optional[myCustomClassType]
```

If your variable should only hold `myCustomClassType` values, then you should use the first variant and be sure to assign a value before using it.

Answer (score 7):

A name with just an annotation is syntactically legal, but doesn't actually create a variable.

```
>>> foo: int
>>> foo
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'foo' is not defined
```

The correct type for `myVar` would be `Union[myCustomClassType,None]` or its equivalent `Optional[myCustomClassType]`, to allow for the assignment of `None`.

```
from typing import Optional

myVar: Optional[myCustomClassType] = None
```

---

Somewhat related, if you define a function like

```
def foo(bar: int = None):
    ...
```

`mypy` will silently "promote" the type of `bar` to `Optional[int]` based on the assigned default value. It doesn't appear to do the same in the case of a variable annotation, though. PyCharm appears to follow suit.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do

```
myVar = None
```

without the type annotation. You can assign a `myCustomerClassType` instance later.